# iTunes is not showing the supported languages for React Native App

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I added support for multiple languages for a react native project using i18nJs. Since we are handling the localization manually, I added the language keys to CFBundleLocalizations. However, upon the release of the app, iTunes is not showing the languages specified in CFBundleLocalizations. It's showing only English.

[image: My app showing only one langauge]
[image]

Comment: You must use ISO 639-1 or ISO 639-2 language code names in your plist

Comment: Thank you for your reply @vishal. I'm using the appropriate format in info.plist. The language keys are "en", "es", "fr", "de". Could it be that I have to manually add a language support from Xcode? https://imgur.com/a/MYXgOrJ

Comment: Yes, I think that will help u for sure follow my steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the Project > Info tab, under Localization add one entry for each language the app supports. This will create one folder for each, e.g. es.lproj, fr.lproj etc. In itunes the localization's will be recognized.

**Update:**
Change the content of localized files, to do the same follow this link here  https://hackernoon.com/localize-an-application-name-in-react-native-c36c4b2be7c3

Comment: Thank you! Do I have to add anything in the created files? I'm handling translation internally using i18nJs. it's not pulling strings from the native side.

Comment: Thank you @vishal. My app name will be the same for all languages. Do I still have to create the InfoPlist.string file for each language?

Comment: oh okay, then no need. I'll make sure that I give you a complete solution by the EOD.

Comment: my pleasure, happy coding :)